# Combining two "patterns" in a @Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I currently have a:

> @Pattern(regexp="\p{Alpha}+", message="Only Alphabetic chars allowed")

That restricts the user to only use Alphabetic chars. But I'm trying to also allow the user to use "Space".

I have figured out that the "pattern" for space is:

> \\p{Blank}

But I need help combinig the two, so you can write both alphabetic chars and spaces.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a character class `[...]`:

```
@Pattern(regexp="[\\p{Alpha}\\p{Blank}]+",
         message="Only Alphabetic and Blank chars allowed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Pattern(regexp="\p[{Alpha}{Blank}]+"...` or even simplify this as following:

`@Pattern(regexp="\p(\w|\s)+")`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `\p` does. Also, `\w` doesn't mean "alphabetic character", it means "word character", which is quite different.